# How to Don't sum button onclick every AJAX success jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

sorry if my title qustion not better because i confused.

The case:
I make looping post timeline like Facebook, and each post have comments. The structure like this:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Post 1 #id-321**
__ Have 10 comments (show_again_321) <- [this button loadmore comment, show 2 comment on each click]

**Post 2 #id-876**
__ Have 17 comments (show_again_876) <- [this button loadmore comment, show 2 comment on each click]

**Post n.....**

+++++++++++++++++++++++++

I make this code in WordPress.

```
// Load more reply
        var cur_page = 1;

        $( document ).on( 'click', 'button[class*="show_again_"]', function() {
            var reply_id = $( this ).attr( 'reply-id' );

            var reply_data = {
                action: 'ajax_replyto_loadmore',
                reply_id: reply_id,
                cur_page: cur_page,
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: reply_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( response, result, xhr ) {
                    console.log(response);
                    cur_page++;
                }
            });
        });
```

And function like this:

```
function ajax_replyto_loadmore() {
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $reply_to = '_bbp_reply_to';
    $paged = esc_attr( $_POST['cur_page'] + 1 );
    $reply_id = esc_attr( $_POST['reply_id'] );
    $post_reply = bbp_get_reply_post_type();

    $get_reply_to = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = %s
        AND meta_value IN ( $reply_id )
        ",
        $reply_to
    ) );

    foreach ( $get_reply_to as $key => $value ) {
        $list_reply_to[] = $value->post_id;
    }

    $args_to = array(
        'post__in' => $list_reply_to,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type' => $post_reply,
        'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ),
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $the_query_to = new WP_Query( $args_to );

    if ( $the_query_to->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $the_query_to->have_posts() ) : $the_query_to->the_post();
            $article[] = '<li>' . bbp_get_reply_content( get_the_ID() ) . '</li>';
        endwhile;
    endif;

    $datareply = array(
        'xxx' => 'yyy',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'get_reply_to' => $article,
        'reply_id' => $reply_id,
    );

    wp_send_json( $datareply );

    // reset postdata
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}
```

Now, if button show_again_xxx clicked they retrun sum $paged.,

Case:

- Button show_again_321 click [return $paged = 2]
- Button show_again_876 click [return $paged = 3]

I don't want it, i want each button show_again_xxx licked, they not sum $paged return.,

This console log result

[image]

If you understand with my problem, help me.. please.....

**Updated solution:**

```
// Load more reply
        // var cur_page = 1;

        $( document ).on( 'click', 'button[class*="reply_loadmore_"]', function(e) {
            var cur_page = $( this ).attr( 'cur-page' );
            var reply_id = $( this ).attr( 'reply-id' );

            var reply_data = {
                action: 'ajax_replyto_loadmore',
                reply_id: reply_id,
                cur_page: cur_page,
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: reply_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( response, result, xhr ) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $( '.reply_loadmore_' + reply_id ).attr( 'cur-page', response.paged );
                    cur_page++;
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set paged inside HTML content like some hidden input, like you do for `reply_id`. Then on reponse update it with response `$paged` value. Also, you will  have to remove `var cur_page = 1;`

Something like this:

// Load more reply

```
    $( document ).on( 'click', 'button[class*="show_again_"]', function() {
        var reply_id = $( this ).attr( 'reply-id' );
        var cur_page = $(this).attr('cur_page');


        var reply_data = {
            action: 'ajax_replyto_loadmore',
            reply_id: reply_id,
            cur_page: cur_page,
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: reply_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( response, result, xhr ) {
                console.log(response);
                cur_page++;

            }
        });
    });
```